# VSCode triple click: do not select new-line character

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when you triple click, it selects the whole line, including the new-line character at the end of the line.

Is there away to select only up to right before the new-line?  I can do this with a combination of keyboard shortcuts (select line, select one character back), or a macro, but not with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this behavior is very anoying.  The issue is not with the selection or the subsequent cut/copy, but with the paste action, which deliverers the "/n" new line formatting to the code editor.  An option in VScode to remove the "/n" of pasted content that was selected via tripple-click (whole line selection) would be very useful.

thx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).